# How to disable close button of windows mobile 6.5 forms

Tags: windows-mobile, windows-mobile-6.5, windows-mobile-6, windows-mobile-6.1

I m creating a windows mobile application. In the application i do not want to show the 
close button of form (That appears on the top right corner of the screen)
Is there any way to do this?

Any help appreciated 
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 4):

Set the Form's `ControlBox` Property to `false`.

Comment: Would be nice if the OP accepted or commented as to why he didn't accept this answer...

Answer (score 0):

It depends on having the close button hidden all the time or just for the one or other form:

http://www.hjgode.de/wp/2012/05/10/windows-mobile-kiosk-mode-series-part-1/